# mysqli and php (loop and single data)

Tags: php, mysqli

i made this php script:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
 // output data of each row
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

     echo "<br> ID: ". $row["id"]. " - Nome: ". $row["ragione_sociale"]. "<br>";
     echo "<br> Località: ". $row["localit"]."<br>";


};


while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo "<br> Macchinario: ". $row["aspetti_generali"]."<br>";
};
```

But don't work, the second loop for "aspetti_generali" not appear.

What am I doing wrong?

full query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM scheda_cliente, localit, irr_spalleggiate WHERE scheda_cliente.id = $id and localit.idl = scheda_cliente.localita and irr_spalleggiate.idr = scheda_cliente.id GROUP BY scheda_cliente.id";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Comment: This is failing you `while ($row` - you're using the same function (OOP and procedural) and that alone will throw you an error. get rid of the 2nd one and put `echo "<br> Macchinario: ". $row["aspetti_generali"]."<br>";` inside the first one.

Comment: how can I solve my problem?

Comment: reload my comment above. or use a different variable. `$row2`. - `while ($row2...` - `$row2["aspetti_generali"]`

Comment: or your query failed. Add `or die(mysqli_error($conn))` to `mysqli_query()`.